# Eval function in list comprehension gives name error

Tags: python, list-comprehension, nameerror

```py
def print_formatted(number):
    for n in range(number):
        n+=1
        methods = ['int', 'oct', 'hex', 'bin']
        ls = [eval(method + '(n)') for method in methods]
```

I don't know why doesn't eval() work in list comprehension.

Comment: what do you expect your output to be in `ls`? Why are you using `eval`? I don't think [it does what you think it does](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#eval).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`eval()` is overkill here. These builtins are objects in their own right. There's no need to go through strings.

Adding 1 to `n` every loop isn't required because you could start your range at 1 and end one later.

And you're not actually printing or returning the list. You could do a `print(ls)` or something.

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for n in range(1, number+1):
        methods = [int, oct, hex, bin]
        ls = [method(n) for method in methods]
        print(ls)
```

And these aren't technically "methods" since they're not attached to a class.

---

Another issue is that comprehensions have their own local scope, as if you had defined a generator function (one that contains a `yield`). The `n` from the surrounding (nonlocal) scope was never used in the comprehension, so the compiler didn't include it in the comprehension's locals, so `eval()` couldn't see it. You can explicitly pass in the namespace you want to `eval()` though.

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for n in range(number):
        n+=1
        methods = ['int', 'oct', 'hex', 'bin']
        loc = locals()  # gets local namespace outside of comp as a dict
        ls = [eval(method + '(n)', loc) for method in methods]
        print(ls)

print_formatted(4)
```

```
[1, '0o1', '0x1', '0b1']
[2, '0o2', '0x2', '0b10']
[3, '0o3', '0x3', '0b11']
[4, '0o4', '0x4', '0b100']
```

You could also use `n` in the comprehension somewhere so that the compiler will include it inside the comprehension's locals. (`eval()` defaults to using the local namespace when you don't provide one.) It's not enough to include `n` in the `eval()` string because that could change at runtime, which is after the time the compiler has to decide what the locals for the comprehension are.

```
def print_formatted(number):
    for n in range(number):
        n+=1
        methods = ['int', 'oct', 'hex', 'bin']
        ls = [eval(method + '(n)') for method in methods for _ in [n]]
        print(ls)
```

I am not recommending you actually do this. The above is only to explain what's going on here, in case you were using a minimal example illustrating the problem for a case that does need `eval()`, but you don't need `eval()` at all here.

Code should be comprehensible for humans (readability counts) otherwise we'd all still be using assembly language. Too much magic can be confusing. String metaprogramming with eval/exec is about the strongest magic built in to Python. Easy to use, but difficult to use correctly. Avoid it when you don't need it. Even if you think you need it, you probably don't: `eval()` is way overused by beginners (of those who know it exists) and they almost never need it.

Answer (score 1):

It does work, however eval doesn't understand `'(n)'` (n is not resolved). Try as follows:

```
number = 5

def print_formatted(number):
    numberlst = []
    for n in range(number):
        # n+=1  <-- not needed
        methods = ['int', 'oct', 'hex', 'bin']
        ls = [eval(method + '('+ str(n) + ')') for method in methods]
        numberlst.append(ls)  # <-- add list for each value of n
    return numberlst

for lst in print_formatted(number):
    print(lst)
```

Outputs:

```
[0, '0o0', '0x0', '0b0']
[1, '0o1', '0x1', '0b1']
[2, '0o2', '0x2', '0b10']
[3, '0o3', '0x3', '0b11']
[4, '0o4', '0x4', '0b100']
```

Comment: I don't think the `n` is the issue, it's working fine for me. However you may be right that if OP is trying to return `ls` then they need make changes accordingly for that.

Comment: It is an issue: `Traceback (most recent call last):
  ...
  File "F:\pybin\StackOverflow\so.py", line 8, in print_formatted
    ls = [eval(method + '(n)') for method in methods]
  File "F:\pybin\StackOverflow\so.py", line 8, in <listcomp>
    ls = [eval(method + '(n)') for method in methods]
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'n' is not defined`

Comment: It works for me, but I'm guessing if you're calling it as a module from another file then there may be some weirdness with namespace. However for fixing that, I would look at gilch's answer.

Comment: Mmm, I was not calling it as a module, but actually posted the file exactly as I ran it on Python 3.6 under Windows. There must be something else that is causing the difference in behavior.

Answer (score 0):

Part of your code is totally fine.

```
methods = ['int', 'oct', 'hex', 'bin']
ls = [eval(method + '(n)') for method in methods]
```

should work as intended.

I don't know why you would be getting a name error. It would be best if you gave us the full trace so we can help you debug.

The only mistake I see is that you have `n+=1` in your for loop. You don't need to increment `n` because `for n in range(number):` already increments it.